# how to shell script write multi line text to file read from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I am facing a problem while writing a shell script. i have table in a database where there is a text field.. i need to write that field into a file.

database fields are id, file_name, text

here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -a row
do
cat <<EOF >/root/${row[1]}
${row[2]}
EOF
sleep 1
done < <(echo "SELECT * FROM installation WHERE status = 1" | mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -padmin -D data -s)
```

I have tried with

```
echo "${row[2]}" > /root/${row[1]}
```

But its writing the 1st line only, but the
text field is multiline text and i need write full text in that file

please help

Comment: why mix languages,just  do it all with php

Comment: does printf work instead?

Comment: yo use PHP for all of it. Scour thru its functionality to do what you want (which is unclear to me). Jumping out to a shell is about the furthest thing one ought to think of. It blows performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `read -r row` will do word splitting by space/tab/new-line. Because the text field from table contains new-lines, word splitting would cut your text result. In this situation it's hard to avoid it.

I recommend you should replace the new-line to another mark, e.g. ### or just `new-line`, using `REPLACE(text, "\n", 'new-line')`(I am not familiar with sql REPlACE function) in SQL, then get result from shell, then use `${row[2]//new-line/$'\n'}` to convert the new-line back.